# Incorrect SVG rendering on iOS browsers

Tags: html, ios, svg, safari, mobile-safari

I'm trying to place an SVG icon inline with some text. It currently works perfectly on all browsers that I've tested, apart from those on iOS.

The issue that I'm having is that on iOS, sometimes, the shapes drawn in the SVG will shift to the left, compared to its background. You can see this happen in this minimal example:

```html
Sm
<svg viewBox='0 0 2 2' height='1em' width='1em' style='background-color: black'>
  <rect fill='red' x='0' y='0' height='1' width='2' />
</svg>
```

Where on most browsers, the red rectangle will be correctly aligned with the SVG's background, but on iOS, it will be 1 pixel to the left.

You may notice the 'Sm' at the start of the line, since it seems there needs to be some amount of text to trigger this bug (if you remove the 'm', it renders correctly on all browsers).

I am curious if this is intended behaviour or not, since I couldn't find any reference to this. If this is intended behaviour/a known bug, is there a fix to make iOS browsers work properly?

Comment: why use a class that doesn't exist (`icon-background`)? especially for a "minimal example" ?

Comment: `x` and `y` don't need to be specified here since [they default to 0 anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/rect#attributes), and even with specifying them explicitly, the SVG is rendered incorrectly.

Comment: This SO clip reproduces the bug correctly in iOS safari, but when I copy this code over to a codepen the bug doesn't appear and the alignment is correct. This would lead me to believe that this is an iOS bug with unknown triggers. Other methods (like a 50:50 red/black linear gradient) might not trigger this bug. Good luck!